# How can I fix a problem about getLoaderManager().initLoader?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have finished the course about `Android Basics: Data Storage`, and I have built a new project which is quite the same as the Pets app. But I have found that there is a difference between my code and the Pet app code. The one which has a red line is my code. I have a question, why that code line is different from the code which is in Pet code?

My code:

[image: The Pet Code]

With the red line:

[image: The highlighted code.]

Comment: Well, that seems to be just a naming difference. The pet app is name `Pet App` while your is something like the 'The secret App'.

Comment: That's why you get `SECRET_LOADER` in your project and `PET_LOADER` in the other project. Or that's what I think.

Comment: Please add your code in text format in your post, not with a picture

Answer (score 2):

You've set a breakpoint. Just click on the red circle and the highlight will go away.

You can find more information about breakpoints and debugging [here](https://blacklenspub.com/5-debugging-tips-with-android-studio-65751011262f)